# Spring LDAP - bind for successful connection

Tags: spring-security, ldap, bind, spring-ldap

I'm trying to authenticate and then query our corporate LDAP using Spring LDAP and Spring security. I managed to make authentication work but when I attempt to run search I always get the following exception

> In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection

After much research I have a theory that after I authenticate and before I can query I need to bind to connection. I just don't know what and how?

Just to mention - I can successfully browse and search our LDAP using JXplorer so my parameters are correct.

Here's section of my securityContext.xml

```
<security:http auto-config='true'>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reports/goodbye.html" 
            access="ROLE_LOGOUT" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reports/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:http-basic />
    <security:logout logout-url="/reports/logout" 
            logout-success-url="/reports/goodbye.html" />
</security:http>
<security:ldap-server url="ldap://s140.foo.com:1389/dc=td,dc=foo,dc=com" />
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider">
</security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
<!-- Security beans -->
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://s140.foo.com:1389/dc=td,dc=foo,dc=com" />
</bean>
<bean id="ldapAuthProvider" 
   class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="foo.bar.reporting.server.security.ldap.LdapAuthenticatorImpl">
            <property name="contextFactory" ref="contextSource" />
            <property name="principalPrefix" value="TD\" />
            <property name="employee" ref="employee"></property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="foo.bar.reporting.server.security.ldap.LdapAuthoritiesPopulator" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<!-- DAOs -->
<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
  <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
```

Here's code snippet from `LdapAuthenticatorImpl` that performs authentication. No problem here:

```
@Override
public DirContextOperations authenticate(final Authentication authentication) {
    // Grab the username and password out of the authentication object.
    final String name = authentication.getName();
    final String principal = this.principalPrefix + name;
    String password = "";
    if (authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
        password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    }
    if (!("".equals(principal.trim())) && !("".equals(password.trim()))) {
        final InitialLdapContext ldapContext = (InitialLdapContext)
     this.contextFactory.getContext(principal, password);
        // We need to pass the context back out, so that the auth provider 
        // can add it to the Authentication object.
        final DirContextOperations authAdapter = new DirContextAdapter();
        authAdapter.addAttributeValue("ldapContext", ldapContext);
        this.employee.setqId(name);
        return authAdapter;
    } else {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Blank username and/or password!");
    }
}
```

And here's another code snippet from `EmployeeDao` with my futile attempt to query:

```
public List<Employee> queryEmployeesByName(String query) 
   throws BARServerException {
    AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
    filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "person"));
    filter.and(new WhitespaceWildcardsFilter("cn", query));
    try {
        // the following line throws bind exception
        List result = ldapTemplate.search(BASE, filter.encode(), 
            new AttributesMapper() {
            @Override
            public Employee mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) 
                throws NamingException {
                Employee emp = new Employee((String) attrs.get("cn").get(), 
                   (String) attrs.get("cn").get(),
                        (String) attrs.get("cn").get());
                return emp;
            }
        });
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        throw new BarServerException("Failed to query LDAP", e);
    }
}
```

And lastly - the exception I'm getting

```
org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: 
    Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is 
    javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr: 
    DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind 
    must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece]; remaining name 
    'DC=TD,DC=FOO,DC=COM'
```

Comment: I know this is old but @Bostone can you help me sort this out. I am getting exact same exception, however i am getting this error on the login page where user first enters credentials. The ldap returns successfully when correct username and password is entered but i get following error: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece ]; remaning name ''

Comment: @user1647708 please see my answer below. It worked for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your LDAP is configured to not allow a search without binding to it (no anonymous bind).  Also you have implemented `PasswordComparisonAuthenticator` and not `BindAuthenticator` to [authenticate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html) to LDAP.

You could try modifying your `queryEmployeesByName()` method to bind and then search, looking at some examples in the [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/site/reference/html/basic.html).

Comment: This reads like a comment, what do you suggest? I know it's possible since I can use JXplorer (which is java app) to connect and search LDAP I just can't figure out how to bind. I think I tried BindAuthenticator in the past and ended up with same exception

Comment: @Droidln.net. Edited the answer with explicit suggestion.

Comment: This is very doc that I used to code authentication. When they are talking bind/unbind they mean inserting/deleting records in that particular example

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to accept @Raghuram answer mainly because it got me thinking in the right direction.

Why my code was failing? Turned out - the way I wired it I was trying to perform anonymous search which is prohibited by the system - hence the error.

How to rewire example above to work? First thing (and ugly thing at that) you need to provide user name and password of user that will be used to access the system. Very counterintuitive even when you login and authenticated, even if you are using `BindAuthenticator` system will not attempt to reuse your credentials. Bummer. So you need to stick 2 parameters into `contextSource` definition like so:

```
   <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://foo.com:389/dc=td,dc=foo,dc=com" />
    <!-- TODO - need to hide this or encrypt a password -->
    <property name="userDn" value="CN=admin,OU=Application,DC=TD,DC=FOO,DC=COM" />
    <property name="password" value="blah" />
</bean>
```

Doing that allowed me to replace custom implementation of authenticator with generic `BindAuthenticator` and then my Java search started working

Comment: Did you set the values for the `userDn` and `password` to the real values? I mean if I do this, everyone will see it in plain text. How can I read it for example from a login form?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, couldn't find a solution.
Finally I changed the application pool identity to network service and everything worked like a charm.
(I have windows authentication and anonymous enabled on my site)